# set title of image document to display in browsers

Tags: php, mongodb

I have an applicaton written in PHP that retrieves files from mongoDB Grid collection, and allows a user to view/download them based on if they're an image or not.

It's all working fine, except that the title bar of the browser displays the name of the php file I'm running the script in, rather than the filename of the image that's displayed. for example:

```
myphpfile (JPEG 1024 X 768 pixels)
```

I'm not sure if it's possible, but I'd like to change it if it is. If I right-click and select save as I get the correct image name, as user header() I've set:

```
content-disposition: inline; filename="thefilename"
```

I've also tried setting name with the content-type with no success.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you cant your serving the script file so it's the URL regardless of content

Comment: That's a shame, I thought that may well be the case. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible way is not to open image directly in the browser's window, but a simple HTML code like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Put your title here
</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src='your_script_generating_images.php?parameters'>
</body>
</html>
```

But did you think about some fancy and nice solutions like http://highslide.com/ or http://fancybox.net/? All that you need is to set the links to your script generating images and to update the page title correspondingly (which is not even required as you can write information you want just above the image in popup).

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't really thought about going that route to achieve it.